# Remoting solution

Tags: windows, android, remote-access

I have tried Teamviewer and Windows Remoting.

I have 2 problems:

1. I have some requirements about which devices/user accounts should have access to which devices. With teamviewer I have to create one account for each remoting client, and then enter a lot of cryptic password for each remoted machine.  Also I sometimes want to give external workers access to several machines (I need to keep track these, and easy remove the privileges)
2. In teamviewer, when I want a presentation, I have to approve it on the remote machine, which is inconvenient. Strangely, if I want normal remoting, (running a desktop session on the remoted machine), I don't need to approve on remoted machine.
   Are there any good remoting solutions which addresses these to issues better?

In addition, it could be useful to have the possibility for remote management, or having access to resources on the machine (such as files or access to media) through the remoting infrastructure. (Teamviewer will let me transfer files).

Mainly Windows machines, with Android Tablets and phones.